# How can I use CKEditor with dompdf to get a reliable PDF with side by side images and tables?

Tags: pdf, ckeditor, wysiwyg, dompdf

I have a client who needs to have a robust WYSIWYG Editor to be able to create a relatively complicated page with side by side images, tables and columns which must also be able to be converted into a PDF reliably.  Unfortunately CKEditor can sometimes generate some funky HTML which looks fine on the page, but doesn't work so well when dompdf converts it to a PDF.  Does anyone have any experience with this or have any ideas on how to get these two systems to work together?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the funky HTML. Probably what you want to try is running the HTML created by CKEditor through something like [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net). At least, it's a good first start.

Comment: If that doesn't work you might consider setting up CKEditor templates or widgets that can be inserted by a button click (widgets is probably not the correct CKE term).

Comment: Also potentially helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9019741/264628